# What is the proper way of implementing form input validation with stateless components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

So I've recently started working with react-native and I would obviously like to use best practices to work on my apps. That's why I decided to use redux and follow the advice to write stateless, functional components.

Once I got used to it and established some standards it worked great for a while: I write a functional component, map state and dispatch to its props and have a store that keeps track of how things are and gets injected by `Provider`.

Things got complicated once I got into making validation for my form input component. Say I want to have a component that can validate its input and display error if there is a problem. I can obviously add some state to my global store for this, but I don't want to have a place in my global store for each input that I use in my app. This might be in contrast to what is taught about using redux, but I have a feeling what I want is not that impractical.

So to give an example of what I want:

```
const Input = ({ error }) => {
  let style = styles.input;
  const onChange = (val) => {
    // change the error here, say
    if(val === 'test') error = null;
    else error = 'must be test';
  };
  if (error) {
    style = styles.inputError;
  }
  return (
    <TextInput
      style={style}
      onChangeText={onChange}
    />
  );
};
```

But I wouldn't like to have to connect error to a global state.

Is this too much to ask, or have I overlooked the way to make `Input` refresh itself (I can't get `this` in it at all)?

I get that this is a more of a philosophical question, as there is an obvious solution of creating ES6 class for your component and using `setState`. I'm mostly interested in hearing about some approaches to solving this problem and if there is a problem at all, or I'm just being too stubborn. :)

Comment: Is using react state in a parent non-functional component a solution ? Otherwise you shouldn't use functional component if you want to control your input.

Comment: I don't have non-functional components. Is there a reason I should not use functional component if I want to control my input? What if I want parent to set my components input? Is there a way to accomplish that while keeping parent functional?

Comment: 1 . Keep it in your Redux state , 2 .  have a non-functional component which react state and onChange handler, 3 . Validate input on submit only , not like you do onChange={myHandler}

Comment: Valid points, so easiest way is to have ES6 class that can control its own state and use that. Unfortunately it's not an option to have input validation on submit.

Comment: So yes, you should go with a non-functional for this purpose, there is not much you are missing with this approach in terms of performance

Comment: I figured there is a way actually: you can introduce another `Provider`, with 'local store' that is made for each component, has dummy reducer and keeps local component state. That way you can keep all components functional. Not sure if there are any problems with that approach (maybe it can interfere with your global state), but I will probably write an answer for stubborn people like myself, maybe someone will find it useful.

Comment: So what you mean by localStorage is redux , isn't it ? Or I couldn't follow.

Comment: Yeah, it's redux, but not your global state, but a store that can handle only your component's state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I mentioned this was pretty much a meta question, but for me was a significant one, as I learned a lot while fiddling with it.

Hopefully what I learned will help someone running into same issue and save him time needed to research this topic with so little online resources:

1. You can't and probably shouldn't be able to access your pure control from inside of it.
2. If you do have to create your control as ES6 class and access `this`, even your linter won't complain anymore because that is fine use case, so there are a couple of cases where it's OK to extend `Component`.

Example of the control that uses these two conclusions looks like this:

```
class Input extends Component {
  render() {
    let style = styles.input;
    const error = this.state && this.state.error;
    const onChange = (val) => {
      if (val === 'test') this.setState({ error: null });
      else this.setState({ error: 'test required' });
    };
    if (error) {
      style = styles.inputError;
    }
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={style}
        onChangeText={onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Now, since I am stubborn I learned one more thing: it's possible to make it with just pure components. Like I stated in the comments somewhere, it is possible to make a local store, wrap your component in `Provider` and connect to it the same way you are used to while using functional components. I am not sure how useful will it be, but I will provide the example:

```
const localStore = createStore(
  (state = [], obj) => (obj ? { errorMessage: obj.error } : state),
  { errorMessage: null },
);

const inputWithStore = ({ error }) => {
  let style = styles.input;
  const onChange = (val) => {
    if (val === 'test') localStore.dispatch({ type: 'unused', error: null });
    else localStore.dispatch({ type: 'unused', error: 'test required' });
  };
  if (error) {
    style = styles.inputError;
  }
  return (
    <TextInput
      style={style}
      onChangeText={onChange}
    />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ error: state.errorMessage });

const InputWithStore = connect(mapStateToProps)(inputWithStore);

const Input = () =>
(
  <Provider store={localStore}>
    <InputWithStore />
  </Provider>
);
```

I will still appreciate hearing about other approaches and comments about these. Thanks.

Comment: I am the same decision fork and even though I liked your idea, it would be also interesting to hear other cases.

Comment: Hm, interesting comment, unfortunately probably not a lot of people stumble upon this, so I have sent my future self to give you a second opinion:
The truth is probably you want your commonly used components stateless in the end. So even your input would itself be dumb, it would have everything passed to it. You absolutely need to have a stateful parent component (so you should ignore my stubbornness above). In an example from above, your parent component would be form. It would handle logic behind what your dumb input component renders.
Not in depth explanation, but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I agree and thanks for comment. atm there isn't any other answer but I voted up for question because I like the thread of thought. Will follow.